# Uneditable black faces in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

Using Sculpt Mode, I accidentally pressed <kbd>B</kbd> and now some of the faces are black:

[image: Black faces in Sculpt Mode]

These faces are no longer editable. **What have I done and how can I edit the faces again?**

I tried checking my key bindings to find out what <kbd>B</kbd> does, but I am not able to find any information on this.

Comment: And for @Frithjof, try clearing the sculpt mask with Alt + M.

Comment: @TLousky That fixed it. Thank you very much.